# Ensemble Kalman Filter SLAM

Tags: kalman-filter, slam, reference-request

I know that there is an extended kalman filter approach to simultaneous localization and mapping.  I'm curious if there is a SLAM algorithm that exploits the ***ensemble*** kalman filter.  A citation would be great, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well let's see. [The original paper](http://enkf.nersc.no/Publications/eve94a.pdf) has approximately 3,000 citations in various branches of literature, including numerous applied textbooks. I'd say this question lacks research, but given the large amount of follow-up literature, I understand how you may not be able to find a SLAM-specific implementation.

I was able to find many papers using enKF/enEKF for visual applications, but relatively few for true map-based SLAM. (I think the term SLAM is over-used and over-specific, but that's an aside.) If you relax your definition of a map to be any feature tracked across multiple sensor measurements, then you should also include:

- Vehicle to vehicle localization.
- Visual feature tracking
- Target tracking from emplaced sensor measurements
- Self localization and state estimation

But, doing a search for "SLAM" in the context of directly citing the enKF article yielded only the following:  [State estimation of connected vehicles using a nonlinear ensemble filter](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11771-015-2767-4)

This does not preclude enKF-SLAM since my search was restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out this website?http://enkf.nersc.no/
It seems that the authors have an extended literature on enKF and examples in Matlab and Fortran are provided.

Comment: There is no enKF SLAM algorithm in the website you linked.